# Springboot, how to show Banner programmtically at start, again

Tags: java, spring-boot, banner

If a springboot application starts, a logo/banner is shown.
I took my own, colored banner in a banner.txt file. It is shown at starts, all is fine.

But I want to repeat my banner after successfull or not successfull start as last startup message. Like:  Banner + "runs" or Banner + "do not run".

Something like this:

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
   {
     try {
      SpringApplication.run( ControllerUndMain.class, args );
           showLogo();
           System.out.println('runs')
        } catch(Exception e){
           showLogo();
           System.out.println('not working')
        }
}
```

This helps our admins and devops to see, that startup phase ends and if applications run or not.

Question: How to show banner programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

I could not found any straight way of doing it. I did a drive into spring code base and found way of doing that. I've tested in my project and its working fine.

Note: I've copied some of the class which are used by spring to print banner. I don't see any issue on reusing in our code base.

Here is a entire code....

Main class which runs springboot application and I've created method to print banner.

```
public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(DemoApplication.class);

        ConfigurableApplicationContext test = app.run(args);

        DemoApplication application = new DemoApplication();
        application.printBanner(app, test);
    }

    public void printBanner(SpringApplication app, ConfigurableApplicationContext test) {
        ResourceLoader resourceLoader = (app.getResourceLoader() != null ? app.getResourceLoader()
                : new DefaultResourceLoader(app.getClassLoader()));
        SpringApplicationBannerPrinter bannerPrinter = new SpringApplicationBannerPrinter(resourceLoader, null);
        Banner banner = bannerPrinter.print(DemoApplication.class, test.getEnvironment());
        banner.printBanner(test.getEnvironment(), DemoApplication.class, System.out);
    }

}
```

After adding above code base just copy *SpringApplicationBannerPrinter* and *SpringBootBanner* class(You will get those form Spring code base) in your project and run.

Note: 1) I've tested before posing answer here. 
      2) To make answer short, I've not pasted *SpringApplicationBannerPrinter* and *SpringBootBanner*. Let me know if you want me to paste those class in answer

Comment: Thanks you! SpringApplicationBannerPrinter.class is not public. I have to override with my own BannerPrinter to use it. I found a better and easer solution.

Comment: >I found a better and easer solution
Can you share with me? it will help me to improve my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SimpleDemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final SpringApplication app;
    final ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
    app = new SpringApplication(SimpleDemoApplication.class);
    context = app.run(args);

    print(context);
}

public static void print(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
    Banner banner = context.getBean(Banner.class);
    banner.printBanner(context.getEnvironment(), SimpleDemoApplication.class, System.out);
}
```

}

Just inject or get over context.getBean the org.springframework.boot.Banner.class. This helps for the good case, if all is fine and context is up.

I dont have a solution for the bad case, if context dont running.

Comment: Ohh..Almost identical but your solution better. I should have thought of using "context.getBean(Banner.class);" instead of copying class :)